# Get the script of django database

Tags: sql-server, django, database

I have to modify my models but I alredy have data in my databse, and I have to clean it to modify my models, How can I make an script file with all the inserted data of django database in order to clean my database and have the data in a script and the uploaded it into the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to dump data into a json file.

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-primary --indent 4 > initial_data.json
```

Once you have json file, just use this to load it into database.

```
python manage.py loaddata initial_data.json
```

Also, You said you have to modify your models, Once you do that you wont be able to load it. since schema would have been changed.

Comment: if i want to save the results into a textfile ?

Comment: When I use the command I get: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd3' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: hmm May be sql server does not like unicode ? I am not familiar with sql-server., but try enforcing a unicode charset.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special to preserve the data in your database. Django's migrations are specifically designed to alter existing tables as well as creating new ones.